# XSL-FO How can i get dynamic static content according to attribute value

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to create a static-content using a template call.
Each of my elements has an attribute "pagemaster" that has exactly the name of one of my declared simple-page-master master names. Based on this attribute I decide which simple-page-master is used for each element.
Now I would also like to use this attribute to determine which static-content should be rendered on the page.

My previous consideration is as follows:

```xml
              <fo:layout-master-set>
                       .
                       .
                       .
             </fo:layout-master-set>

             <xsl:for-each-group select=".//reportelements/*[pagemaster != '']" group-adjacent="pagemaster">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">

                    <!-- Here is my Problem. This should call the Template below -->
                    <!-- What i want to achieve is that if "{current-grouping-key()}" is "TITLEPAGE" then the Template below gets called -->
                    <xsl:call-template name="{current-grouping-key()}"/>

                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
      </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TITLEPAGE">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C:\Logo.pdf)" content-width="6cm"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem i have now is that i get the following Error: 
`Static error in xsl:call-template/@name on line 59 column 73 of masterpage_report.xsl:
  XTSE0020: Invalid QName {{current-grouping-key()}}`

Comment: `xsl:call-template/@name` is defined as a QName (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#named-templates).  (XSLT 3.0 lets you have leading and trailing white-space in the attribute value, but that's all that changed.)  As such, you can't use an expression for the `@name` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you could replace the `xsl:call-template` with an `xsl:apply-templates` to process the pagemaster element in a 'static-content' mode:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="pagemaster" mode="static-content" />
```

The `@match` attributes of templates in the 'static-content' mode would include a predicate that ensures that the template for the `pagemaster` value is the one that is processed:

```
<xsl:template match="pagemaster[. = 'TITLEPAGE']"
              mode="static-content">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block text-align="right">
            <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C:\Logo.pdf)" content-width="6cm"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>
```

If you are not otherwise processing `pagemaster` elements, then you might not even need the separate mode.

Answer (score 0):

change code:-

```
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="{current-grouping-key()}">
 <xsl:call-template name="{current-grouping-key()}"/>
            to

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="current-grouping-key()">
<xsl:call-template name="current-grouping-key()"/>
```

Comment: Ok not completely the same but nearly: `Static error in xsl:call-template/@name on line 59 column 71 of masterpage_report.xsl:
  XTSE0020: Invalid QName {current-grouping-key()}`

Comment: i dont understand? What should i delete? if i use `<xsl:call-template name="current-grouping-key()"/>` i get the same Error as before...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a global parameter or variable in the form of

```
<xsl:param name="static-content">

    <content name="TITLEPAGE">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:C:\Logo.pdf)" content-width="6cm"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
    </content> 

    <!-- add other named "content"s here -->
</xsl:param>
```

and then, instead of `<xsl:call-template name="{current-grouping-key()}"/>` you use `<xsl:copy-of select="$static-content/content[@name = current-grouping-key()]/*"/>`.

For efficiency, you could also declare a key `<xsl:key name="static-content" match="content" use="@name"/>` and then you would use `<xsl:copy-of select="key('static-content', current-grouping-key(), $static-content)/*"/>`.